# How to find just one group a user is logged in as

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code which displays each group a user is logged in:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Groups();
    }

    public ArrayList Groups()
    {
        ArrayList groups = new ArrayList();

        foreach (System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference group in

            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Groups)
        {

            groups.Add(group.Translate(typeof

                (System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString());

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < groups.Count; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(groups[i].ToString() + "");
        }


        return groups;
    }
```

Some of the groups that displays are:

```
BUILIN\Administrators
Everyone
IIS_Usrs
tmg\IT Members
tmg\Domain Users
```

How do I check if a user is in the `tmg\IT Members` group only?

I tried the following but it failed because some group didn't have the `\`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < groups.Count; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(groups[i].ToString() + "");
            string t = groups[i].ToString().Split('\\')[0];
            string y = groups[i].ToString().Split('\\')[1];
            MessageBox.Show(t);
            MessageBox.Show(y);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < groups.Count; i++){
  if ( groups[i].ToString() == @"tmg\IT Members" ) 
  {
     ...    // true...
  }
}
```

Comment: inside the for loop or I don't need it?

Comment: you don't need a loop, the logic says if the number of groups equals 1 AND that group name equals `tmg\IT Members`  ....

Comment: i forgot the `.ToString()`

Comment: Thank you for correcting. The code isn't working because when I used the for loop one of the popup was `tmg\IT Members` but with the above logic it doesn't work.

Comment: `if (groups.Count == 1 && groups[0].ToString() == @"tmg\IT Members")
  {
   MessageBox.Show("YES");
  }
  else
  {
   MessageBox.Show("NO");
  }`

Comment: @SiKni8 If it doesn't work, state **how**. You can also update your question to show the code you're using (although I'd leave the original part intact in this case).

Comment: It keeps displaying "NO"

Comment: right, you sure that .`ToString()` is resulting in the group?  why don't you post what debug results in?

Comment: you sure `Count == 1` is true?  get all the facts... this should be an easy fix.

Comment: `groups.Count = 29` in the debug

Comment: I am sorry I think I know what is happening I can remove the first arg, because the code would have to loop through all 29 groups to see if the user belongs in the `tmg\IT Members` group.

Comment: That's exactly what I edited to... and it's working now! Thanks.

Comment: I am wondering if you can also assist me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162698/how-to-cascade-dropdowns-from-left-to-right-and-right-to-left-in-a-sharepoint-we   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity?.Groups?.Where(s => s.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString() == "tmg\\IT Members").ToList().Count == 1)
{

}
```